# Dúvida em relação a manipulação de strings

Tags: c, string, char

Estou começando a programar e estava tentando fazer uma manipulação de strings, alguém poderia me ajudar no código abaixo onde eu estaria errando:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int, char ** )
{

    char nome[] = "zezinho";
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < 500; i++ )
    {
        if ( nome[i]  = "z" );
        nome[i] = "p";
    }
    printf( "%c", nome[i] );

}
```

No compilador dá um erro de conversão inválida de `const char` para `char`.

Comment: Nossa, funcionou perfeitamente. Cara muito obrigado, mas tenho tantas dúvidas. Queria saber 10% do que vc sabe... Um dia chego lá. Mais uma vez obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Você tem vários pequenos erros no código, sendo que  alguns não lhe permitem compilar e outros são mostrados apenas como avisos.

- `int main( int, char ** )` - Falta o nome de cada um dos parametros do `main` sendo que os mais comuns são `argc` e `argv` respetivamente.
- `i < 500` - O seu texto não tem 500 carateres e por isso a partir de determinado ponto, quanto tenta aceder ao caratere vai fazer acessos inválidos na memoria. Correto seria trocar por `nome[i] != '\0'` que testa pelo terminador, ou até utilizando o tamanho do nome obtido com `strlen`.
- `if ( nome[i]  = "z" );` - Comparação é sempre feita com `==` e não `=`, e o `if` nunca leva `;` senão não tem nenhuma instrução associada. Para alem disso o delimitador para um `char` é `'` e não `"`.
- `nome[i] = "p";` - Aqui tem o mesmo problema do delimitador, que deve ser `'` pois estamos a falar de um caratere e não um texto.
- `printf( "%c", nome[i] );` - Se a ideia é imprimir o nome todo a impressão deve ser feita com `%s` e apenas passando `nome` como argumento.

Código corrigido:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char nome[] = "zezinho";
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < nome[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (nome[i] == 'z')
            nome[i] = 'p';
    }
    printf("%s", nome);
}
```

[Veja a correr no Ideone](https://ideone.com/e4Oodw)

Comment: Mais uma dúvida. Qual seria a maneira de entrar dados através do comando SCANF. Estou usando scanf("%c", &nome); e retorna um erro. Qual seria a maneira correta?

Comment: Para uma cadeia de caracteres seria: scanf("%s", cadeia); (sem o & pois cadeia já é um endereço. Atenção que o primeiro espaço é considerado delimitador e encerra a entrada. Para ler até o final da linha use: scanf("%[^\n]s", cadeia);

Comment: @CélioEduardo outra alternativa para além do que o anonimo já disse é utilizar o [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) para ler uma linha inteira se bem que tem mais implicações e tem tendencia a ser mais complicado. O `scanf` com `%s` e respetiva variante de `%[^\n]s` para uma linha inteira é mais simples. Lembre-se que `%c` é para caratere e por isso apenas permite uma letra e o tipo correto tem de ser apenas um `char` e não um vetor de `char`.